# How do I update a heatmap on a different page?

Tags: android, iphone, windows, flutter

So I am completely new to Flutter Programming and I was trying some code-along stuff, particularly [this !](https://youtu.be/2VKpq4h3Sdw).
I am trying to add the heatmap to a separate page, but it doesn't update when there is a change in the data. Could someone guide me as to how I can do that?

this is the map element:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_heatmap_calendar/flutter_heatmap_calendar.dart';
import 'package:my_habits/date_time/date_time.dart';

class MonthlySummary extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<DateTime, int>? datasets;
  final String startDate;

  const MonthlySummary({
    super.key,
    required this.datasets,
    required this.startDate,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: HeatMap(
        startDate: createDateTimeObject(startDate),
        endDate: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 10)),
        datasets: datasets,
        colorMode: ColorMode.color,
        defaultColor: Colors.grey[400],
        textColor: Colors.black,
        //showColorTip: false,
        showText: true,
        scrollable: true,
        size: 40,
        colorsets: const {
          1: Color.fromARGB(30, 216, 143, 255),
          2: Color.fromARGB(55, 216, 143, 255),
          3: Color.fromARGB(80, 216, 143, 255),
          4: Color.fromARGB(105, 216, 143, 255),
          5: Color.fromARGB(130, 216, 143, 255),
          6: Color.fromARGB(155, 216, 143, 255),
          7: Color.fromARGB(180, 216, 143, 255),
          8: Color.fromARGB(205, 216, 143, 255),
          9: Color.fromARGB(230, 216, 143, 255),
          10: Color.fromARGB(255, 216, 143, 255),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is the page that needs to access it. (I created them in separate files as in the video.)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_habits/components/monthly_summary.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:my_habits/data/database.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class MyStats extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStats({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStats> createState() => _MyStatsState();
}

class _MyStatsState extends State<MyStats> {
  final _myBox = Hive.box('myBox');

  HabitDatabase db = HabitDatabase();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Consistency is Key!'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: ListView(children: [
        MonthlySummary(
        datasets: db.heatMapDataSet,
        startDate: _myBox.get("START_DATE"),),
      ],)
    );
  }
}
```

The MonthlySummary class works perfectly when I put it in the page containing the "habit-tiles" as done in the video, but I am unable to get this to work.

Please help! I am a total beginner with this.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers! :)

I don't understand how I can get the chart to update every time there is a change in the data. I want it on a separate page so that I can add a few more charts to that page and show just statistics there. I tried set state for the stateful widget and provider as well but I got confused with the implementation.

[This is the page where the heatmap is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfdWr.png)
[This is the page where I want it to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuCn3.png)

Here's the updated code that is working:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_habits/components/monthly_summary.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:my_habits/data/database.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class MyStats extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStats({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStats> createState() => _MyStatsState();
}

class _MyStatsState extends State<MyStats> {
  final _myBox = Hive.box('myBox');

  HabitDatabase db = HabitDatabase();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    db.loadHeatMap(); //the map was initially returning empty
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Consistency is Key!'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: ListView(children: [
        MonthlySummary(
        datasets: db.heatMapDataSet,
        startDate: _myBox.get("START_DATE"),),
      ],)
    );
  }
}
```